# Mounting an old LVM hard drive

Tags: linux, drive

I am trying to mount an old linux hard drive. It was the old servers hard drive stuck in the new server via a USB port.

I am following the instructions on this page:

[Mounting an old LVM hard drive in Fedora 17 gives error message](https://serverfault.com/questions/451781/mounting-an-old-lvm-hard-drive-in-fedora-17-gives-error-message)

However I am stuck on a part. In the above instructions, he runs lvs and gets:

```
LV       VG         Attr     LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
LogVol00 VolGroup00 -wi-ao-- 461.53g 
LogVol01 VolGroup00 -wi-a---   1.94g
```

However when i run it I get:

```
lv_root VolGroup -wi------- 231.56g
lv_root VolGroup -wi-ao---- 926.75g
lv_swap VolGroup -wi-------   2.00g
lv_swap VolGroup -wi-ao----   4.00g
```

In his you can see they have different names. In mine I can tell which is the old drive (The smaller one) but it is named exactly the same as the other drive? Thus I am not sure which one to mount. This is a live server so I am leery about just randomly mounting things.

Comment: Please use [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts to improve their readability and in particular format console output and Shell commands as `code`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the rest of the guide? You might still be able to activate it (try `vgchange -ay` without parameters) and mount by uuid (look for device files in `/dev/disk/by-uuid`).

Alternatively, you may rename one of your volume groups using `vgrename <uuid> VolGroup00_tmp`. You should be able to get uuid from output of `vgdisplay`. See question [LVM: Duplicate VG name VolGroup00](https://serverfault.com/questions/592543/lvm-duplicate-vg-name-volgroup00) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to use vgdisplay to get the UUID and from there I was able to change the name of the drive:

'code'(vgrename R8pJbF-Zl0G-mcXg-CEQI-8b03-TbwM-boaX3O  VolGroup00_tmp)
Volume group "VolGroup" successfully renamed to "VolGroup00_tmp"